# Looking to make my program BFS algorithm more efficient

Tags: python, graph, breadth-first-search

I am working on a program that does a Breadth First Search on a series of connected links, and should output a print statement telling me what links to cut. The links to cut will block a certain agent from going to its present location, to one of the exit gateways scattered around the graph.

[image]

The image shows exactly what the program does, and what it shouldn't do at the same time. The green dotted links are those that I am printing, which will cut the path to the red coloured bobnet agent to the light blue coloured exit gateways.

Here is the mapping of the inputs for my program:

Initialization input:
Line 1: 3 integers N L E

- N, the total number of nodes in the level, including the gateways.
- L, the number of links in the level.
- E, the number of exit gateways in the level.

Next L lines: 2 integers per line (N1, N2), indicating a link between the nodes indexed N1 and N2 in the network.

Next E lines: 1 integer EI representing the index of an exit gateway node.

So what happens in my program is that, as you can see, the program checks the location of the agent, and cuts the most probable link next to it. However, there seems to be a more efficient program, which instead of finishing in 39 moves like in my case, ends with less, and I want to ask for help finding what is wrong with my program to effectively manage to make it more efficient:

```py
import sys
from collections import deque

class Binder:
    
    def __init__(self, id, pre_binder):
        self.id = id
        self.pre_binder = pre_binder
        
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        # n: the total number of nodes in the level, including the gateways
        # l: the number of links
        # e: the number of exit gateways
        n, l, e = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
        self.graph = {i: [] for i in range(n)}

        for _ in range(l):
            # n1: N1 and N2 defines a link between these nodes
            n1, n2 =  [int(j) for j in input().split()]
            self.graph[n1].append(n2)
            self.graph[n2].append(n1)

        self.exit_gateways = [int(input()) for _ in range(e)] # the index of a gateway node

    def breadth_first_search(self, root):
        print(f"Graph nodes: {self.graph}", file=sys.stderr)

        visited, queue = set(), deque([Binder(root, None)])
        visited.add(root)

        while queue:
            binder = queue.popleft()
            vertex = binder.id
            print(f"Bobnet Location: {self.graph[vertex]}", file=sys.stderr)

            for neighbor in self.graph[vertex]:
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    visited.add(neighbor)
                    new_binder = Binder(neighbor, binder)
                    queue.append(new_binder)

                if neighbor in self.exit_gateways:
                    return Binder(neighbor, binder)
                            
def trace_and_cut_link(result_binder):
    current_binder = result_binder
    while current_binder.pre_binder is not None:
        previous_binder = current_binder.pre_binder
        link_to_cut = (previous_binder.id, current_binder.id)
        print(f'Cutting link: {link_to_cut}', file=sys.stderr)
        current_binder = previous_binder
    print(link_to_cut[0], link_to_cut[1])

game = Game()

while True:
    node_index = int(input())  # The index of the node on which the Bobnet agent is positioned this turn
    result_binder = game.breadth_first_search(node_index)
    trace_and_cut_link(result_binder)
```

```
Game information:
Graph nodes: {0: [2, 10, 9, 5, 12, 11, 17, 7, 13, 14, 6, 3, 4, 15, 1, 16, 8], 
1: [2, 17, 0, 37], 
2: [0, 37, 1, 3, 35], 
3: [34, 0, 2, 4], 
4: [5, 33, 0, 3], 
5: [4, 0, 6], 
6: [5, 0, 7], 
7: [8, 0, 6], 
8: [7, 9, 0], 
9: [0, 10, 8], 
10: [0, 11, 9], 
11: [10, 0, 12], 
12: [0, 11, 13], 
13: [14, 0, 12], 
14: [13, 0, 15], 
15: [16, 14, 0], 
16: [17, 15, 0], 
17: [16, 0, 1], 
18: [26, 24, 23, 22, 27, 25, 21, 19, 20], 
19: [27, 20, 18], 
20: [19, 21, 18], 
21: [29, 22, 18, 20], 
22: [18, 23, 21, 36], 
23: [18, 24, 35, 22, 37], 
24: [18, 23, 25, 37], 
25: [26, 24, 18], 
26: [18, 25, 27], 
27: [19, 18, 26], 
28: [36, 32, 34, 31, 35, 29, 33, 30], 
29: [21, 30, 28, 36], 
30: [31, 29, 28], 
31: [30, 28, 32], 
32: [28, 33, 31], 
33: [32, 4, 34, 28], 
34: [3, 35, 28, 33], 
35: [37, 34, 23, 28, 36, 2], 
36: [28, 22, 35, 29], 
37: [35, 2, 23, 1, 24]}

Block the Agent!
Agent is at position 37

Standard Output Stream:
37 35
Game information:
Link [37-35] severed
Agent moved from 37 to 2

Standard Output Stream:
2 0
Game information:
Link [2-0] severed
Agent moved from 2 to 35

Standard Output Stream:
35 28
Game information:
Link [35-28] severed
Agent moved from 35 to 23
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you think there is better algorithm then maybe you should ask on similar portal [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please provide the input that needs to be fed to `input()` in order to reproduce the case you are discussing with that image and with a number of moves -- which at the moment is not clear as we don't know how the agent moves. Moreover, I am not going to translate your image to an input file. Please provide it.

Comment: @trincot you're right , sorry. I added examples of the moves, and comments to clarify the inputs.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is not enough to test a solution so that it could have less than 39 moves.

Comment: However, the image shows less than 39 edges that are connected to those blue triangles. I suppose if you just cut those and no others, you should have a solution that beats that 39.

Comment: Ok. I apologize, I am quite new to these sort of puzzles, and programs as well. What else can I provide? I thought I had made a practical error, rather than theoretical.

Comment: Sure, but we are no computers (at least not me). I need to test my work. So I need the full graph specification (as input for the constructor) and the route of the agent (as input for the program).

Comment: BTW, I only count 34-35 edges that are dotted, so I don't know where you get that 39 from, and I can't run your program to check what it outputs, since I don't have the input. So that is where it stops for me.

Comment: I have tried to print the graph nodes representation. I hope this is useful.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] instead. Also, think about the "minimal" part thereof and how it relates to the graph. To me, the graph seems to be way too large for a simple (!) demo. Further, replace manuall input with hard-code values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two improvements possible:

1. Don't only *report* that an edge ("link") is cut, also *remove* it from your graph, otherwise you risk to report the same edge in one of the next rounds. And when you do remove it, don't forget to remove it in both directions.
2. Instead of cutting the edge near the *agent*, cut the edge that is closest to the *exit gateway*.

For the example graph that would ensure you only cut 35 edges as then the exit gateways are completely detached from the rest of the graph.

If these improvements are not enough, then here is an additional idea:

3. When finding the shortest path, also find *all* alternative paths of the same length, and only then exit the breadth-first search. This means your BFS has to be adapted considerably: don't mark nodes as visited until you have found all paths of the same length, where multiple paths may end at the same node. Don't exit the search when you find an exit, but continue a bit more until you have all paths of the same length to that exit.

Then check which edge in these paths is shared most often, and cut *that* edge. For example, if you have this situation:

```
                            *------exit
                           /      /
           *-------*------*------*
          /       /
      agent------*
```

...then you should find 4 different paths from agent to exit, and the edge at the center will be in all four paths. So that is the most frequently used edge and should be cut.

Comment: I'm not sure if implementing the 3rd part would have done better, because it was already quite hard to implement the first and second ones. These solved the issue, thank you so much !

Comment: Glad to hear you could implement it with success!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the agent from going FROM its current location to any nodes, it is sufficient to cut all the out edges from its present location.

If I am interpreting your image correctly, that means cutting three edges ( blue lines )

[image]

In any case this is a trivial task and does not require BFS.